# Grabbing the value of an form row on button click where both have the same className

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple rows like the following:

```
const postsOffCountry = <td>{props.posts.map((post => (<input key={post.rowid} defaultValue={post.lcountry} className={post.ref}
onBlur={(event) => props.variables.setLoadingCountry(event.target.value)}></input>)))}</td>;

const postsUpdateButton = <td>{props.posts.map((post, i) => (<button key={i} className={post.ref} onClick={(event) => {props.variables.update(event.target.id);}}>Update</button>))}</td>;
```

Each row has its own update button. My question would be: Is there a way, where i can grab the Value of the row where the button className is the same as the row, where the button has been pressed.

Comment: It'll help if you include the code in question in your post.

Comment: im mapping the props to display the data in lines the variables are put into the correct order in the return for the component before getting exported. my question would be how can i set the useState variables for the entire row with the correct values when the button with the same className is clicked